# IBM Watson Speech To Text using Python Requests Broken Pipe

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests, ibm-watson

I'm trying to make a python script to access IBM Speech-To-Text. I tried to make an equivalent command to cURL example on their site:

> ```
> curl -X POST -u <username>:<password>
> --header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
> --header "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
> --data-binary @<path>0001.flac 
> "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true&timestamps=true&max_alternatives=3"
> ```

and I came up with the following:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/flac',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
}
auth = (USERNAME, PASSWORD)
data = open(audio_name, 'br')
r = requests.post('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true&timestamps=true&max_alternatives=3'
                  , headers=headers, data=data, auth=auth)
```

First command executes fine from terminal while second one gives me:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'` and change `br` to `rb`. The `requests` library will set the right headers.

On the other hand, I recommend you to use the WDC Python SDK which will make your life easier.

Install it using `pip`:

```
pip install watson-developer-cloud
```

Then:

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1


speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    username='YOUR SERVICE USERNAME',
    password='YOUR SERVICE PASSWORD',
)


with open(join(dirname(__file__), './0001.flac'), 'rb') as audio_file:
    print(json.dumps(speech_to_text.recognize(
          audio_file, content_type='audio/wav', timestamps=True,
          continuous=True, timestamps=True, max_alternatives=3
         ), indent=2))
```